# Hyperledger Composer: fabric-ca request register failed with errors after machine restart

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I had a composer-rest-server running on a host. Due to some reason I had to reboot my aws instance. So I stopped all the fabric docker containers except the chaincode and also stopped the composer rest server.

After rebooting the machine, I restarted all the containers. At this time the chaincode container did not start. However, I issued a ping command with admin identity card and the chaincode container too started.

Next, I restarted the composer rest server with the same admin identity. However, when I tried to issue an "identitiy request" command for a participant it resulted in:

> Unhandled error for request POST /api/system/identities/issue: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]

Does it mean the old admin identities are invalidated after a system restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because when the AWS instance reboots, the identity data within the fabric-ca container is cleared (the container uses sqlite for an ephemeral data store).

If you instead setup the fabric-ca container to use a mysql or postgresql db container, you will be able to persist the identity data even after machine/container restarts.

This question also pertains to your situation as well [Hyperledger Composer Identity Issue error after network restart (code:20, authorization failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506355/hyperledger-composer-identity-issue-error-after-network-restart-code20-author/)

Comment: Great, now I get it. I'll try to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually seen when you try and Issue a New Identity whilst using an Identity that does not have the rights to do so.

(If you are in single user mode the card you started the REST server with does not have the rights, or if in Multi-User mode the card currently being used in the Wallet does not have the rights.)

The Network Admin card initially created to administer the network has the rights to Issue New identities, and if you want to create additional Identities (Cards) that have the right you need to give them `issuer` rights when you create them.  This is an option you use when Issuing an identity.  On the CLI you would use a command such as `composer identity issue -c admin@my-network --issuer -u mynewuser ...`

On the REST server you would include an option in the JSON data e.g.:

```
{
"participant" : "org.acme.mynetwork.Manager#MGR02",
"userID" : "BrianM",
"options": {"issuer":true}
}
```

Comment: I'm in a multi-user mode and current default identity is that of Network Admin. Before restarting the aws instance, this card was able to issue identities. However, after I stopped the docker containers, restarted the host and started the containers again, I was not able to issue identity using the same network admin card. Note: I did not prune the docker container or volume. I just stopped the container & started them again. They were still in the swarm and connected on the same channel and the chaincode container got restarted after I tried to ping the network with this admin card.

Comment: I tried the same on a new instance and got the same error. Fabric CA register is not able to recognize the network admin card after host machine restart. Or the other way, is this card invalidated? However, I'm able to start the rest server in single as well as multi mode using this network admin card.

Comment: After you have imported the card can you perform other activity on the REST server, such as GET an asset or Participant?  If you cannot then perhaps you are trying to import a Card with a one-time secret after the secret has been used/invalidated?  If the Card works OK on the Command Line, you could try exporting a new copy from the command line and importing that new copy into the REST server.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue as @MrudavShukla.  Any progress so far?

Comment: @ZackMcGinnis No. Actually, there's an additional problem as well. If you delete the card from the wallet using "composer card delete -c <card-name>" and then import the same card file again, it gives a similar error.